# Javascript Add a list of objects into existing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of objects in array and i would like to assign the whole list with numbers,i have added my list below what am looking for

[image]

I can produce numbers with for loop below.

```
var points = new Array(100);
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        points[i] = i + 1; 
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
     console.log("number:",points[i]);
```

List of my arrays

```
   var jarray = [];
for (var i=0; i<this.admission.length && i<this.fevscore.length; i++)
    jarray[i] = [this.admission[i], this.fevscore[i]];
    this.admissionData = jarray[0][0]
    this.FevData = jarray[0][1];
```

Looking for a result below:

```
0: {number:1 ,date0: "2015-01-28", date1: "2015-02-04"}
1: {number:2 ,date0: "2015-08-27", date1: "2015-09-07"}
2: {number:3 ,date0: "2015-12-24", date1: "2016-01-05"}
3: {number:4 ,date0: "2016-02-23", date1: "2016-03-01"}
4: {number:5 ,date0: "2016-05-29", date1: "2016-06-12"}
5: {number:6 ,date0: "2016-10-24", date1: "2016-10-29"}
6: {number:7 ,date0: "2017-03-26", date1: "2017-04-21"}
7: {number:8 ,date0: "2017-06-22", date1: "2017-07-08"}
8: {number:9 ,date0: "2017-07-26", date1: "2017-08-12"}
9: {number:10 ,date0: "2018-04-24", date1: "2018-05-13"}
10: {number:11 ,date0: "2018-10-10", date1: "2018-10-21"}
11: {number:12 ,date0: "2018-10-24", date1: "2018-11-01"}
12: {and so on... date0: "2019-01-27", date1: "2019-02-12"}
13: {date0: "2019-02-02", date1: "2019-02-13"}
14: {date0: "2019-06-16", date1: "2019-07-10"}
15: {date: "2015-01-28", value0: 6.5}
16: {date: "2019-01-27", value0: 12.2}
17: {date: "2017-07-26", value0: 6.4}
18: {date: "2017-06-22", value0: 12.2}
19: {date: "2015-12-24", value0: 12.2}
20: {date: "2016-10-24", value0: 9.5}
21: {date: "2015-08-27", value0: 12.5}
22: {date: "2018-10-10", value0: 9.6}
23: {date: "2018-10-24", value0: 12.1}
24: {date: "2016-05-29", value0: 10.9}
25: {date: "2019-02-02", value0: 13.3}
```

Comment: That's an array. Nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a text format and only exists while being transferred or stored.

Comment: In the `for` loop, add a `.number` property to each element: `array[i].number = i + 1;`

Comment: JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a textual data interchange format and language-independent. Use this tag when this text format is involved. DO NOT USE the "json" TAG FOR NATIVE JAVASCRIPT OBJECTS OR JAVASCRIPT OBJECT LITERALS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map for this, for example:

```
const list = [
  { name: 'foo', value: 1 },
  { name: 'bar', value: 2 }, 
  { name: 'zzz', value: 3 }
];
const listWithIndex = list.map((item, index) => (
  { ...item, index }
));

console.log(listWithIndex)
// [
//   { name: 'foo', value: 1, index: 0 },
//   { name: 'bar', value: 2, index: 1 },
//   { name: 'zzz', value: 3, index: 2 }
// ]
```

**I strongly recommend you to read the [map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) before implement this solution**

Comment: i am looking to add numbers inisde the result your method is giving an index values which i already have.    0: {number:1 ,date0: "2015-01-28", date1: "2015-02-04"}

Comment: @Sam Check if now makes sense for you

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use a forEach array function to assign your number attributes. It is a little bit more concise and readable than a regular for loop.

```
points.forEach( (elem, index) => elem.number = index + 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map and assign new property for each object:

```
const arrayWithNums = points.map((point, index) => point.number = index + 1);
console.log(arratWithNums);
```